# Exclude duplicates for Text array

Tags: excel, formula

[image]

I have used the following formula to get unique OP for each row:

```
=@FILTER(A2:D2,ISERROR(MATCH(A2:D2,$E$1:E2,0)))
```

and drag down

- R1 John James Martin Andrew Mary - Output = John
- R2 John James Martin Andrew Mary - Output = James because john is already the OP above

It does not always work - sometime it ignores column A - any help appreciated

Comment: Do you have a visual representation of this data? Rather markdown, including desired results.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A2:E))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone - my error - i was including each row output as part of its own check - basic i know!